# Check if file/folder exists, if so delete it, if not display message... trouble in AppleScript

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, applescript

```
set theFile to (("Macintosh SSD:private:var:root:Desktop:new") as text)
 set status to false as boolean

tell application "Finder" to if exists theFile then set status to true
 if status is true then
  delete theFile
else
 display alert "No file."
end if
```

With this code I get the alert "No file" as expected when the file/folder named "new" is not on the desktop, however when the file is there it will not delete it and instead gives me a script error. Any suggestions on how to fix this? many thnx!


[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- You are checking a literal string (text) rather than a file.
- The `delete` line needs to tell the `Finder` to do the job.

This is a simpler version of the script. `path to desktop` points always to the desktop folder of the current user.

```
set theFile to (path to desktop as text) & "new"
tell application "Finder" 
   if exists file theFile
      delete file theFile
   else
      display alert "No file."
   end if
end tell
```

Apart from the issues most likely you have not enough access privileges to write into /private/var/...

Comment: I am running this while logged into the root user account.

Comment: What if I need to delete something from another users desktop and not the desktop of the account that I am logged into? I think command "path to desktop" only works for the account that I'm currently in.

Comment: Then I'd recommend to use the shell.

Comment: Using shell did the job.

Answer (score 0):

There are two style path in AppleScirpt.Those are HFS and POSIX. You can do it like this.

```
--set theFile to "Macintosh HD:Users:mac:Downloads:1024.png"
set theFile to POSIX file "/Users/mac/Downloads/1024.png"

set status to false as boolean

tell application "Finder" to if exists theFile then set status to true
if status is true then
    display alert "file exist"
else
    display alert "No file."
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

just try:

```
set daFile to "/Macintosh SSD/private/var/root/Desktop/new"
try
    do shell script "ls \"" & daFile & "\""
on error
    display dialog "File Does Not Exist!!!"
end try
```